# Resolve SQL Server consuming long execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query is of a view for which a top 10 * taking 1 minute 58 seconds sometime 2 minutes 30 seconds also, need help to tune the query all the joined tables have indexes already created.

The below query has CTE expressions and multiple joins and case statements. Need help on tuning the below query.

```sql
WITH CrmStatus AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            ESTAT,
            StatusShortDesc,
            sp.ProcessType
     FROM refCRMStatus cs WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN refCRMStatusProfile sp ON sp.Processprofile = cs.ProcessType),
CTEOrgMaan1 AS
    (SELECT Sorg.DistributionChannel AS DistributionChannel,
            SO.Objectname AS SalesOffCode,
            SOr.Objectname AS SalesOrgID,
            SGrp.Objectname AS SalesGroup,
            dvnb.DivisionName AS Brand,
            Sorg.[H_CRMDOrgmanHSK],
            Lnkorg.[H_CMRDLinkHSK],
            [H_OpportunityHSK]
     FROM [dbo].[S_CMRDOrgman] Sorg WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[L_CMRDLinkOrgman] Lnkorg WITH (NOLOCK) ON Lnkorg.[H_CRMDOrgmanHSK] = Sorg.[H_CRMDOrgmanHSK]
          INNER JOIN vw_DivisionorBrand dvnb ON dvnb.DivisionCode = Sorg.DIVISION
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[refSalesOfficeCRM] SO ON SO.[SalesOfficeID] = Sorg.SALESOFFICE
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[refSalesOrgCRM] SOr ON SOr.[SalesOrgID] = Sorg.SALESORG
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[refSalesGroupCRM] SGrp ON SGrp.[SalesGroupID] = Sorg.SalesGroup),
CTEAppoint AS
    (SELECT HO.H_OpportunityHSK,
            HO.ProcessType AS BusinessTransType,
            refPt.ObjectType AS ObjectType,
            refPt.processDesc AS ProcessDesc,
            LeadGUID AS CRMOrderGUID,
            SA.[APPLGUID],
            SA.[APPTGUID],
            SA.AppntID,
            SA.ApptType AS AppointmentType,
            SA.ApptText AS TextofAppointment,
            SA.[CreatedBy],
            SA.[ChangedBy],
            SA.Startdate,
            SA.FromTime,
            SA.[AppntStartTimeZone] AS AppointmentStartTimeZone,
            SA.[AppntStartTime] AS AppointmentStartTime,
            SA.EndDate,
            SA.ToTime,
            SA.[AppntEndTimeZone] AS AppointmentEndTimeZone,
            SA.[AppntEndTime] AS AppointmentEndTime,
            SA.CreationDate,
            SA.CreationTime,
            SA.TimeStampCreation,
            SA.ChangedOn,
            SA.LastChangedAt,
            SA.[TimeStampChangeTime] AS TimeStampOfChangeTime
     FROM [dbo].[H_Opportunity] HO
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[L_AppointmentorderADM] LA ON LA.[H_OpportunityHSK] = HO.[H_OpportunityHSK]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].s_Appointment SA --with (index ([NonClusteredIndex-20200507-034807]))  
         ON LA.[L_AppointmentOrderADMHSK] = SA.[L_AppointmentOrderADMHSK]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[refProcessType] refPt ON refPt.[ProcessType] = HO.ProcessType)
SELECT a.*,
       CTEOrgMaan.SalesOffCode,
       CTEOrgMaan.SalesGroup,
       CTEOrgMaan.SalesOrg AS SalesOrgID,
       CTEOrgMaan.DistributionChannel,
       CTEOrgMaan.Brand
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
             CApp.H_OpportunityHSK,
             CApp.BusinessTransType,
             CApp.ObjectType,
             CApp.ProcessDesc,
             CApp.CRMOrderGUID,
             CApp.[APPLGUID],
             CApp.[APPTGUID],
             CApp.AppntID,
             CApp.AppointmentType,
             CApp.TextofAppointment,
             CApp.[CreatedBy],
             CApp.[ChangedBy],
             CApp.Startdate,
             CApp.FromTime,
             CApp.AppointmentStartTimeZone,
             CApp.AppointmentStartTime,
             CApp.EndDate,
             CApp.ToTime,
             CApp.AppointmentEndTimeZone,
             CApp.AppointmentEndTime,
             CApp.CreationDate,
             CApp.CreationTime,
             CApp.TimeStampCreation,
             CApp.ChangedOn,
             CApp.LastChangedAt,
             CApp.TimeStampOfChangeTime,
             PARTNERFCT AS PartnerFunction,
             rfct.DESCRIPTION AS PartnerDesc,
             PartnerNo,
             Partnerguid,
             MainPartner AS MainPartnerFlag,
             St.[Stat] AS Status,
             stu.[StatusShortDesc],
             CASE WHEN CC.CompanyName IS NOT NULL THEN CC.CompanyName ELSE CI.FullName END AS CustomerName,
             CONVERT(varchar(MAX),
                     CASE
                          WHEN CC.H_EngageCustomerHSK IS NOT NULL THEN CC.H_EngageCustomerHSK
                          ELSE CASE
                                    WHEN CI.H_EngageCustomerHSK IS NULL THEN CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, (HASHBYTES('Md5', 'NA')))
                                    ELSE CI.H_EngageCustomerHSK
                               END
                     END) AS CustomerHSK,
             CASE WHEN CC.CustomerType IS NOT NULL THEN CC.CustomerType ELSE CI.CustomerType END AS CustomerType
      FROM [dbo].[H_CMRDPartner] Hp
           LEFT JOIN [dbo].[S_CMRPartner] Sp ON Hp.[H_CMRDPartnerHSK] = Sp.[H_CMRDPartnerHSK]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[L_CRMDPartner] LCP ON LCP.[H_CMRDPartnerHSK] = Hp.[H_CMRDPartnerHSK]
           LEFT JOIN [dbo].[L_CRMDCustomerPartner] CCP ON CCP.[H_CMRDPartnerHSK] = Hp.[H_CMRDPartnerHSK]
           LEFT JOIN S_CustomerCompany CC ON CC.H_EngageCustomerHSK = CCP.[H_EngageCustomerHSK]
           LEFT OUTER JOIN S_CustomerIndividual CI ON CI.H_EngageCustomerHSK = CCP.[H_EngageCustomerHSK]
           LEFT JOIN CTEAppoint CApp ON CApp.H_OpportunityHSK = LCP.H_OpportunityHSK
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[S_CRMOrderADMStatus] St ON St.[H_OpportunityHSK] = CApp.H_OpportunityHSK
           INNER JOIN CrmStatus stu ON stu.ESTAT = St.Stat
                                   AND stu.processType = CApp.BusinessTransType
           LEFT JOIN refCRMCPartnerFCT rfct ON rfct.[PARTNER_FCT] = Sp.PartnerFCT
      WHERE Sp.PartnerFCT = '00000009') a
     INNER JOIN vw_getCRMDOrgman_new CTEOrgMaan ON CTEOrgMaan.H_OpportunityHSK = a.H_OpportunityHSK;
GO
```

Comment: This isn't something we can simply "fix" there's a lot going on in that query. If a query is los, one of the first things I check though is do I *really* need the `DISTINCT`s; they can very very expensive. Certainly the last one will be very expensive. Otherwise post the query plan using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) until you know you need it and you understand the consequences and accept the errors that it might generate. Nested views, mixed use of inner and outer joins, and splattering DISTINCT are also bad signs. And just because a table has an index does not make that index useful generally or to this particular query.